# IIS usernames in ELK stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok, nxlog

I am having an issue that I am trying to resolve with IIS logs and Elasticsearch. What is happening is that my usernames in the IIS logs have a backslash () in them and not a forward slash (/). When Elasticsearch returns names it no longer has the \ which I would have hoped would have been escaped when entered. So when viewing the results in Elasticsearch or Kibana the username has no \ and the slash that is there is being treated as a regular expression. An example of this would be the username abcd\bob would be returned as abcdob.

I also believe that this issue would be the reason I am getting a _grokparsefailure tag added to each entry coming from IIS.

Any suggestions?

My NXLOG file getting the data:

```
    ## Please set the ROOT to the folder your nxlog was installed into,
    ## otherwise it will not start.

    #define ROOT C:\Program Files\nxlog
    define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog

    Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
    CacheDir %ROOT%\data
    Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
    SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
    LogFile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.log

    <Extension json>
        Module      xm_json
    </Extension>

    #<Extension w3c>
      #map iis log fields to Field Types
    #    Module      xm_csv 
    #    Fields      $date, $time, $website, $serverip, $method, $url, $querystring, $port, $username, $clientip, $version, $useragent, $referer, $status, $substatus, $sc_win32_status, $sc_bytes, $cs_bytes, $time_taken
    #    FieldTypes  string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer
    #    
    #    #Fields      $date, $time, $website, $hostname, $serverip, $verb, $request, $querystring, $dstport, $user, $clientip, $httpversion, $useragent, $cookie, $referrer, $fqdn, $status, $substatus, $sc_win32_status, $sc_bytes, $cs_bytes, $time_taken
    #    #FieldTypes  string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer
    #    Delimiter   ' '
    #   QuoteChar '"'
    #   EscapeControl FALSE
    #   UndefValue -
    #</Extension>

    <Extension w3c>
      #map iis log fields to Field Types
        Module      xm_csv
        Fields      $date, $time, $website, $hostname, $serverip, $verb, $request, $querystring, $dstport, $user, $clientip, $httpversion, $useragent, $cookie, $referrer, $fqdn, $status, $substatus, $sc_win32_status, $sc_bytes, $cs_bytes, $time_taken
        FieldTypes  string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, integer, integer, integer, integer, integer
        Delimiter   ' '
    </Extension>


    # Nxlog internal logs
    <Input internal>
       Module im_internal
       Exec $EventReceivedTime = integer($EventReceivedTime) / 1000000; to_json();
    </Input>


    # Windows Event Log
    <Input eventlog>
    # Uncomment im_msvistalog for Windows Vista/2008 and later 
       Module im_msvistalog

    # Uncomment im_mseventlog for Windows XP/2000/2003
    #   Module im_mseventlog

       Exec $EventReceivedTime = integer($EventReceivedTime) / 1000000; to_json();
    </Input>

    <Input iis-logs>
        Module      im_file
        File 'C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex*.log'
        ReadFromLast TRUE
        Exec        if $raw_event =~ /^#/ drop();                    \
                    else                                             \
                    {                                                \
                        w3c->parse_csv();                            \
                        $EventTime = parsedate($date + " " + $time); \
                        to_json ();                                  \
                    }
    </Input>


    <Output out>
       Module om_tcp
       Host logs.{domain removed}.com
       Port 3515
    </Output>

    <Output iis-out>
        Module      om_tcp
        Host        logs.{domain removed}.com
        Port        3516
    </Output>


    <Route 1>
       Path internal, eventlog => out
    </Route>

    <Route 2>
        Path        iis-logs => iis-out
    </Route>
```

My Logstash.conf file:

```
    input {
        tcp {
            port => 5000
            type => "syslog"
        }
        tcp {
            type   => "eventlog"
            port   => 3515
            codec => json_lines
        }
        tcp {
            type => "iislog"
            port => 3516
            codec => json_lines
        }
    }

    filter {
        if [type] == "syslog" {
            grok {
                match => { "message" => "<%{POSINT:syslog_pri}>%{DATA:syslog_timestamp} %{DATA:syslog_program}\[%{NUMBER:syslog_pid}\]\: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
                add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
    #           add_field => [ "received_from", "%{@source_host}" ]
            }
            syslog_pri { }
            date {
                match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "yyyy:MM:dd-HH:mm:ss" ]
            }
            if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
                mutate {
                    replace => [ "@message", "%{syslog_message}" ]
                }
            }
            mutate {
                remove => [ "syslog_message", "syslog_timestamp" ]
            }
            kv {
                source => "@message"
            }
        }
        if [type] == "eventlog" {
            # Incoming Windows Event logs from nxlog
            # The EventReceivedTime field must contain only digits, or it is an invalid message
    #       if [EventReceivedTime] !~ /\d+/ { drop {  } }
    #       grep {
    #           match => [ "EventReceivedTime", "\d+" ]
    #       }
            mutate {
                # Lowercase some values that are always in uppercase
                lowercase => [ "EventType", "FileName", "Hostname", "Severity" ]
            }
            mutate {
                # Set source to what the message says
                rename => [ "Hostname", "@source_host" ]
            }
            date {
                # Convert timestamp from integer in UTC
                match => [ "EventReceivedTime", "UNIX" ]
            }
            mutate {
                # Rename some fields into something more useful
                rename => [ "Message", "@message" ]
                rename => [ "Severity", "eventlog_severity" ]
                rename => [ "SeverityValue", "eventlog_severity_code" ]
                rename => [ "Channel", "eventlog_channel" ]
                rename => [ "SourceName", "eventlog_program" ]
                rename => [ "SourceModuleName", "nxlog_input" ]
                rename => [ "Category", "eventlog_category" ]
                rename => [ "EventID", "eventlog_id" ]
                rename => [ "RecordNumber", "eventlog_record_number" ]
                rename => [ "ProcessID", "eventlog_pid" ]
            }
            mutate {
                # Remove redundant fields
                remove => [ "SourceModuleType", "EventTimeWritten", "EventTime", "EventReceivedTime", "EventType" ]
            }
            if [eventlog_id] == 4624 {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => [ "ad-logon-success" ]
                }
            }
            if [eventlog_id] == 4634 {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => [ "ad-logoff-success" ]
                }
            }
            if [eventlog_id] == 4771 or [eventlog_id] == 4625 or [eventlog_id] == 4769 {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => [ "ad-logon-failure" ]
                }
            }
            if [eventlog_id] == 4723 {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => [ "ad-password-change" ]
                }
            }
            if [eventlog_id] == 4724 {
                mutate {
                    add_tag => [ "ad-password-reset" ]
                }
            }
            if "ad-logon-success" in [tags] {
                metrics {
                    add_tag => [ "drop", "metric", "ad-logon-success" ]
                    meter => "ad-logon-success-metric"
                }
            }
            if "ad-logon-failure" in [tags] {
                metrics {
                    add_tag => [ "drop", "metric", "ad-logon-failure" ]
                    meter => "ad-logon-failure-metric"
                }
            }
        }
        if [type] == "iislog"
        {
            grok {
    #    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{WORD:iisSite} %{IPORHOST:site} %{IP:hostip} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:querystring} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clientip} %{NOTSPACE:httpversion} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:sub-status} %{NUMBER:win32-status} %{NUMBER:bytes-received} %{NUMBER:bytes-sent} %{NUMBER:time-taken}"]
                match => ["message", "%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp} %{WORD:sitename} %{HOSTNAME:computername} %{IP:hostip} %{URIPROTO:method} %{URIPATH:request} (?:%{NOTSPACE:queryparam}|-) %{NUMBER:port} (?:%{NOTSPACE:username}|-) %{IP:clientip} %{NOTSPACE:httpversion} %{NOTSPACE:user-agent} (?:%{NOTSPACE:cookie}|-) (?:%{NOTSPACE:referer}|-) (?:%{HOSTNAME:host}|-) %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER:sub-status} %{NUMBER:win32-status} %{NUMBER:bytes-received} %{NUMBER:bytes-sent} %{NUMBER:time-taken}"]
            }
            useragent {
                source => "useragent"
            }
            #geoip {
            #   source => "clientip"
            #}
        }
        metrics {
            meter => "events"
            add_tag => [ "drop", "metric", "events-metric" ]
        }
    }

    output {
        if "drop" not in [tags] {
            elasticsearch {
            host => "127.0.0.1"
            cluster => "logs"
        }
    #       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
        }
    }
```

Sample IIS log entry:

    `2015-05-06 15:41:18 W3SVC2 WEB1 10.11.10.137 GET /main/ - 80 ABCD\smith 10.11.11.127 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+Touch;+.NET4.0E;+.NET4.0C;+Tablet+PC+2.0;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+InfoPath.3) cisession=a%3A4%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22959e25c7a1663350eeb85edb676de096%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A12%3A%2210.11.11.127%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A120%3A%22Mozilla%2F4.0+%28compatible%3B+MSIE+7.0%3B+Windows+NT+6.3%3B+WOW64%3B+Trident%2F7.0%3B+Touch%3B+.NET4.0E%3B+.NET4.0C%3B+Tablet+PC+2.0%3B+.NET+CL%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1430926793%3B%7D08a40eacaf8b6eba6102c7746c35c46497a6502a http://my.domain.com/main/scheduling my.domain.com 200 0 0 11314 1009 1458`

**UPDATE:** 
I added a second nxlog iis input/output and instead of outputting the data to my logstash server I output to a flat file.

```
    <Output iis2-out>
        Module      om_file
        File 'C:\logs\logtest.txt'
    </Output>
```

I checked the output of this and noticed that the username has the backslash removed from the username prior to hitting the logstash server.

Comment: Can you configure logstash to save the **username** as a `not_analyzed` string? Otherwise elasticsearch will keep trying to tokenize you usernames.

Comment: See my update above. Looks like it is a nxlog issue not a logstash.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/nxlog-ce-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg00613.html) is the same issue.
You should disable the default backslash escape character with:

```
EscapeChar 0x00
```